# Finding (and removing) repeating pairs in array

Tags: f#

I want a way to get rid of repeating pairs in an array. For my problem, the pairs will be consecutive, and there will be at most one repeating pair.

My current implementation seems too complicated. The elements 3 and 4 form what I'm calling a repeating pair in arr1 below. As a pair, they only appear once in the desired output, arr2. What are some more efficient ways?

```
let arr1=[|4; 2; 3; 4; 3; 4; 1|]
let n=arr1.Length
let iPlus2IsEqual=Array.map2 (fun x y -> x=y) arr1.[2..] arr1.[..(n-3)]
let consecutive=Array.map2 (fun x y -> x && y) iPlus2IsEqual.[1..] iPlus2IsEqual.[..(n-4)] |> Array.tryFindIndex (fun x -> x)
let dup=if consecutive.IsSome then consecutive.Value+1 else n-1
let arr2=if dup>=n-3 then arr1.[..dup] else Array.append arr1.[..dup] arr1.[(dup+3)..]

>
val arr2 : int [] = [|4; 2; 3; 4; 1|]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use recursion like so (it will get multiple repeats for free too)

```
let rec filterrepeats l =
    match l with
    |a::b::c::d::t when a=c && b=d -> a::b::(filterrepeats t)
    |h::t          ->h::(filterrepeats t)
    |[] -> []

> filterrepeats [4;2;3;4;3;4;1];;
val it : int list = [4; 2; 3; 4; 1]
```

This works on lists, so you will need to add a call to `Array.toList` before you run it.

The above is not tail recursive as the compiler doesn't know what goes on the right hand side of `h::(filterrepeats t)` until after the function call.  You can solve this by using an accumulator like so:

```
let rec filterrepeats l  =
    let rec loop l acc =
        match l with
        |a::b::c::d::t when a=c && b=d ->loop t (b::a::acc)
        |h::t          ->loop t (h::acc)
        |[] -> acc
    loop (List.rev l) []
```

Comment: Your tail recursive version reverses the remaining pair.

Comment: @dood - fixed by swapping the order when joining things

Comment: According to my measurements, this solution is over 35x slower than the original one in the question! :-)

Answer (score 2):

For large arrays this is around 13x faster than your solution:

```
let inline tryFindDuplicatedPairIndex (xs: _ []) =
  let rec loop i x0 x1 x2 =
    if i < xs.Length-4 then
      let x3 = xs.[i+3]
      if x0=x2 && x1=x3 then Some i else
        loop (i+1) x1 x2 x3
    else None
  if xs.Length < 4 then None else
    loop 0 xs.[0] xs.[1] xs.[2]

let inline removeDuplicatedPair (xs: _ []) =
  match tryFindDuplicatedPairIndex xs with
  | None -> Array.copy xs
  | Some i ->
      let ys = Array.zeroCreate (xs.Length-2)
      for j=0 to i-1 do
        ys.[j] <- xs.[j]
      for j=i+2 to xs.Length-1 do
        ys.[j-2] <- xs.[j]
      ys
```

I use `inline` and test elements individually (i.e. rather than as a tuple: `(x0,x1) = (x2,x3)`) to try to prevent `=` from being a generic equality test because that is very slow. I've reused previous array lookups from one iteration to the next. I copy the input array if the output is identical to the input and pre-allocate an array with `n-2` elements otherwise. I've hand-rolled the copying to my pre-allocated array to avoid creating any garbage (e.g. instead of `Array.append` of two slices).

Answer (score 0):

No stack overflow with large list (length >= 100K) and remove all duplicate pairs

```
let rec distinctPairs list = 
    List.foldBack (fun x (l,r) -> x::r, l) list ([],[])
    |> fun (odds, evens) -> List.zip odds evens 
    |> Seq.distinct
```

Not very fast, 1M list take 500ms, anyway faster ?

*Only work for list with even length*

Comment: This will fail when the input list has odd length

Comment: @JohnPalmer I can't comment on your answer (new to stack-oveflow), very nice solution but why f# didn't generate tail-call for it ?

Comment: See my updated answer for why my function wasn't tail recursive and a tail-recursive version

Comment: Yeah, just figure out it :D